# Capturing and saving a picture using UIImagePickerController with custom overlay

Tags: ios, objective-c

I followed the apple docs method of using `UIImagePickerController` with a custom overlay. Right now it is very simple, I only have one button on the overlaying view. This button has the target `takePic`. The only issue with this is that since I am NOT using default camera controls, the `imagePickerController` delegate method is never called after capturing a picture,

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

I think this method is usually called on the default overlay after a user captures a picture and taps "Choose Photo". However in this overlay, all I want is a "take picture" button that takes the picture and saves it.

This is my code:

```
-(void)takePic
{
    [cameraUI takePicture];
    NSLog(@"take pic called");
}

// For responding to the user accepting a newly-captured picture or movie
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {
    NSLog(@"Finished picking media");
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    UIImage *originalImage, *imageToSave;

    // Handle a still image capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0)
        == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                     UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        imageToSave = originalImage;
        NSLog(@"image Saved");

        // Save the new image (original or edited) to the Camera Roll
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (imageToSave, nil, nil , nil);
    }

    // Handle a movie capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
        == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

        NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:
                                UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];

        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (
                                                 moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
        }
    }

    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

As I mentioned previously, `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` is never called. How can I save the picture to the camera roll?

Comment: did you set delegates?

Comment: Yes, I set delegate of `cameraUI` to self (ViewController).

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting your object as the `delegate` of your `ImagePicker`?

If your cameraUI is your `(UIImagePickerController *)` you should have at some point, before presenting cameraUI, have the code `cameraUI.delegate = self;` or whatever controller had the delegate method.